# Entity manager createNativeQuery: Can be vulnerable to SQL/JPQL

Tags: sql, spring-boot, entitymanager, sonarqube-scan

Sonar is reporting "Security-Potential SQL/JPQL injection for the below code.

```java
@Repository
Class EmployeeData {

    @Autowired
    EntityManager em;

    @value($ {"emp.detail.query"})
    String query;

    public List < Employee > getEmpData() {
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(query).setParameter("id", 123);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

I am reading the query from application.properties file and this query is combination of multiple sub queries so I can't go for criteria builder.

When I move this query to some constant file then sonar does not report the issue.

Any idea why sonar report this as a vulnerability when I read this query from application.properties.